# xPages: missing NSF in link using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages, lotus-domino

I am having problems with links in navbar's using Bootcamp in XPages. I have an Internet Site document for develop.test.com. The Home URL on the page is Web/develop.nsf. I have the launch option of the DB set to the xPage xpHomePage.xsp. When I go to develop.test.com my Bootstrap site with menu displays perfectly. My problem is that the links in the navbar are inconsistent. Sometimes I have the DB name included, sometimes not?

The link Abmelden (near the bottom of the code) converts to http://develop.test.com/web/develop.nsf?logout which would be correct. The dropdown "Anwesenheiten/offen nach Name converts to http://develop.test.com/Web/xpAnwesendOffenNachName ==> somehow the develop.nsf is missing? I just cannot work out why.

I could of course just hardcode the NSF into the link - just doesn't seem right to me :o)

Thanking you for any help given.

=========== here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:div id="header" disableTheme="true">
        <!-- This is the banner -->
        <nav class="navbar-header navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="xpHomePage.xsp">
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@DbTitle()}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>
                    </a>
                    <!-- this is the hamburger menu that gets shown when the view is small enough -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Navigation umstellen</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <!-- create a div so the header is collapsed when tiny -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="header-menu">
                  <!--  and now the actual menu -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-inverse">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Anwesenheiten
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="xpAnwesendOffenNachName">offen nach Name</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="xpAnwesendOffenNachStandort">offen nach Standort</a>
                                </li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="xpAnwesendFreiNachName">freigegeben nach Name</a>
                                </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="xpAnwesendFreiNachStandort">freigegeben nach Standort</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="xpAnwesendFreiNachMonat">freigegeben nach Monat</a>
                        </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="?logout">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>
                                <xp:text>
                                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:" Abmelden"}]]></xp:this.value>
                                </xp:text>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </xp:div>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try computing the whole href. It may be doing different things on different pages within the application, depending on context.

Comment: I compluted the href as suggested (although I did need to use a <xp:link> and not a <a> as that did not work). Thank you for the help (here and on twitter :o)